# python re.match group: number after \number

Tags: python, regex, numbers, regex-group

In a Python match pattern, how do I match a literal digit like `1` after a backreference by number like `\1`?

I tried the `\g<1>` syntax that is available in substitution patterns for this purpose, but it doesn't work in my match pattern.

I have a larger problem that I want to solve using a function that will perform the following somewhat unusual task. The task is to construct patterns dynamically so that each pattern will match digit sequences that have repeated digits in certain positions and specific digits in the remaining positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that I don't need the `\g<1>` syntax. Instead I can use one of several techniques to separate the numeric backreference like `\2` from the digit like `9` that follows it. Here are three such techniques:

- a non-capturing group `(?:\2)9`
- an otherwise unnecessary quantification by one `\2{1}9`
- using an otherwise unnecessary character class to contain only the digit that follows the backreference `\2[9]`

Comment: +1 for finding a valid use for `{1}`!  Adding to the confusion, some regex flavors wouldn't need such workarounds in most cases.  If there are only two or three capturing groups, `\29` will be interpreted as a backreference to group #2 followed by a literal `9`.  I don't know offhand if that's true of Python.  Whichever technique you use, I suggest you comment it.

Answer (score 2):

Put the digit that you want to match literally in a character class `\1[1]` or a group `\1(1)` of its own so that the bracket or parentheses separates the digit from the backreference.

Comment: No down vote, but the grouping would be better as a non-capturing group: `\1(?:1)`.